# How to sort an array of objects in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have an object that has two members that are both integer values.  I made an array of these objects.  Each objects values are filled with random integers.

I want to sort the array of objects according to the first member value.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Are you using .NET 3.5? If so, it's as easy as:

```
array = array.OrderBy(x => x.MemberName).ToArray();
```

That will create a *new* array though - if any other code has a reference to the old array, it will still see the unsorted data.

Alternatively, you can use the [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx) method which will sort the array in-place, in one of three ways:

- Make your type implement [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) allowing an object to compare itself with another
- Create an instance of [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) which can compare any two objects of that type
- Create a delegate of type [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) which can compare any two objects of that type

The last is probably the easiest solution if you're using C# 3:

```
Array.Sort(array, (x1, x2) => x1.MemberName.CompareTo(x2.MemberName));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28VS.71%29.aspx) in the class first. These should help:
[Sort ArrayList Of Objects](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/sortarraylistofobjects.html)
[How to use the IComparable and IComparer interfaces in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    class Foo
    {
        public int FirstMemberValue { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foos = new[] 
        { 
            new Foo { FirstMemberValue = 1 }, 
            new Foo { FirstMemberValue = 3 }, 
            new Foo { FirstMemberValue = 2 } 
        };
        Array.Sort(foos, (f1, f2) => f1.FirstMemberValue.CompareTo(f2.FirstMemberValue));
        foreach (var item in foos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.FirstMemberValue);
        }
    }
}
```